# printing all lines after finding a match, excluding the line containing the match. Using grep

Tags: unix, grep

I'm using the following code to print the lines that follow a match from a text file, but my output contains the line with the match. I don't want to include the line containing the match. What am i doing wrong?

```
    grep -A103 "match"  filein > fileout
```

Answer (score 0):

The grep will show the matching line and the additional lines trailing the match.
You can use

```
grep -A103 "match"  filein | grep -v "match" > fileout
```

or any other construction to skip the first line.
Using `tail -103` won't work when you do not have that much lines.

Answer (score 0):

Do it with Perl, like so:

```
perl -ne'print if $found; $found ||= /MATCH/;' filein
```